# How to circumvent JSON.stringify returning undefined in a special case and that way creating an string failing for JSON.parse?

Tags: javascript, json, firefox, windows-7, undefined

I use Windows 7 64 bit, and Firefox 32.
So I have read that JSON.parse can't handle something like `JSON.parse("{ 'a': undefined }";`
But when using JSON.stringify in the following context, I get undefined:

```
console.log("'abc': " + JSON.stringify(this.nothing));
```

results in

```
"'abc': undefined"
```

I'm creating my object-strings in my own functions, but for simplicity in those functions I'm using JSON.stringify for some variables.

I assumed that would bring me on the secure side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the JSON facility incorrectly:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify({ abc: this.nothing }));
```

That will give you the JSON string `"{}"`, which is correct, because `({}).abc` is `undefined`. The JSON spec includes no provision for `undefined`; the only scalar values allowed are strings, numbers, booleans, and `null`. Thus a JavaScript property whose value is `undefined` is "serialized" as not being in the object at all.

Don't use `JSON.stringify()` piecemeal. Create your JavaScript object structure and then stringify the whole thing.

Comment: @John `JSON.stringify(undefined)` will return `undefined`. If you then use that as part of a string concatenation operation, you'll get `undefined` in your assembled string.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `JSON.stringify` to turn values into JSON that is not supported. The value `undefined` is one of those values.

If you use for example `JSON.stringify(null)` you will get the string `"null"` back because that is a supported value. You can see at http://json.org/ what the supported values are.

If you use `JSON.stringify(undefined)` you won't get the string `"undefined"` back. The unsuppored value is omitted from the result, and as that makes the result completely empty (not an empty object or array), the result is the value `undefined`.